# How do I change the thickness of paths in an SVG using Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I have collected SVG icons from different sources. Some use thick paths and shapes. Others use thin ones.

Is there a way to change the thickness of paths and shapes in an SVG without having to adjust all the points in the object?

[image]

Comment: ***Please*** look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes **good** queries, *and* how best to frame. As a whole, questions which would *require access to individual files* are *out-of-scope* as being essentially tech support queries; yours seems *perilously close* to that as currently framed, as we *cannot tell* looking at the `.png`s whether the `.svg`s originally called for 'strokes of varying width' or if those are shaped fills, which would complexify to any answer; please revise your question to better fit the guidelines, perhaps posting the `.svg` code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on how the graphics were constructed.

If it's made of simple strokes, then you could just apply a thinner stroke.

If the strokes have been converted to outlines, all bets are probably off. In this case it would be easier to redraw them as strokes, and apply a thinner stroke.

I don't use Sketch, but the example below was done in Inkscape. I redrew the shapes with the Bézier/Pen tool, and changed the stroke size. It should also be possible in Sketch

[image]

Comment: Thanks Billy. The objects I am trying to modify in Sketch are in Paths in Shape folders. There doesn't appear to be Strokes, or an equivalent in Sketch. I tried increasing the border size of paths to no avail. Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch doesn't have strokes. To make a line icon in Sketch you need to make a smaller version of a path (shape) and change the fill color.

To fix the problem, I had to ungroup the paths, remove the fill color, add a border and increase the thickness.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a path **thicker**, here's an engineer's approach.

Open the SVG file in a text editor (say, Notepad) and look for `<path`. Add the following text right after `<path` : `stroke="color" stroke-width="width"`, where:

- `color` should be the same color as the path. It can be explicitly defined (for instance `#000` for black) or set to `currentColor`, meaning the color of a container.
- `width` is how much the path should be thicker. Try numbers between 1 and the `viewBox` width (`512` in my example below).

The SVG should start looking as this:

```
<svg id="svg-repo-html5" class="svg-repo-html5" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<path stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="10"
```

Sometimes it's a way better just to quickly edit a file than opening it in a WYSIWYG editor.

Unfortunately, you cannot make the path **thinner** this way.